# Microsoft Access 2010: Update a field in another table on button click

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

## Basics about the database

I am working on a (relatively) simple database that stores inventory data.  I am using Microsoft Access 2010 in order to do this.  I have six tables with the following relationships:
[Relationships of Database](http://i42.tinypic.com/a4biup.png)

I have created forms which combine the **Transaction** table with **Ordered**, **Received**, **Allocated**, or **Dispensed**.  Each form requests an amount which will then be used to update *On Hand*, *On Order*, or *Allocated* (from the **Material** table) respectively.

## The Problem

For example, my form to update **Transaction** and **Order** should be able to take in the *Amount* ordered, save all the data from the fields to the **Transaction** and **Order** tables as well as add the amount from *Amount* to *On Order* in the **Materials** table.

---

I have been working on this database for the past two days.  I have searched several times for possible ways to perform a similar function, but have come up with nothing.  All the tutorials I have found which seem remotely close to what I need to accomplish are for versions of Access which are much older than 2010.  Unfortunately I have had little experience with the actual coding within Access, so I am stuck clicking around within the buttons on its menus.

## What I have tried

Currently, the program is set to run the following Update query:
[Screenshot of update query](http://i42.tinypic.com/zlcb6d.png)

This query works if I have one Material stored in the database but adds all the *Amount* values from **Ordered** to *On Order* every time it is ran, which is unfortunately not what I need it to do.  I only need each *Amount* value added to *On Order* once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relate the Ordered and Material tables by adding a foreign key field to the Material table, ex. OrderedFK (Long Integer). This new field must be updated whenever a row is inserted into the Ordered table (assuming the "No" Field is AutoNumber). This is typically performed by using a Form (Ordered) and Sub-Form (Material) and setting the sub-form' Link Master (No) and Link Child fields (OrderedFK).

You can then join the Ordered and Material tables on the Update Query to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I have not used 2010, but on 2007 you can go to Database Tools and then select Relationships. You can then add the two tables, drag from "No" Ordered to OrderedFK and specify Enforce.

Comment: Can the **Ordered** table not pull the Primary Key of **Transaction** that links to **Material**?  My original goal was to use the **Transaction** table as a parent, so that **Ordered** would inherit the link to **Material**.  Before I make any changes to my tables, is it possible to do this within Access?

My goal is to make as few edits as possible.  Do I have to add a foreign key to **Material** for every table which will act on it?  Or is there a way to share the same foreign key for all four tables which will change data within **Material**?

Comment: Please provide a description of the tables. You can include all relevant tables in the Relationships form and take a screen shot. Try to show all fields in each table.

Comment: I included a link to an image of the Relationships form when I first posted, but here is another one [link](http://i42.tinypic.com/a4biup.png).  It contains all tables and fields.

Comment: It appears that you have separated "Amount" in four different tables with a one-to-one relationship. If this is correct, it would be more efficient to include all of these Amount(s) in the transaction table, ex. OrderedAmount, AllocatedAmount, etc. Are the Project and Batch number also the same for each transaction?

Comment: I have "amount" in four different tables because it is four different amounts.  The goal of the program is to allow separate users to alter each area.  One person will change the Order amount, one the Received amount, and so on.  I suppose I could merge the tables, but this would cause a lot of void or null storage to occur.  I didn't combine them for the sake of storage, and to make calling up reports later on easier.

Project and Batch number are not always the same for every transaction for that Material.  Also, a Project number could have several different Batch numbers associated with it.

Comment: From what you have described, the update query would look like: UPDATE (Material INNER JOIN [Transaction] ON Material.Material = Transaction.Material) INNER JOIN Ordered ON Transaction.[No] = Ordered.[No] SET Material.[On Order] = [On Order]+[Amount];
...but I do not think this is correct.

Comment: This statement is very close to what I need to happen.  I'll continue playing around with it until I can get the call to work properly.  Thank you very much for your help!